# Why is min-height not being respected when it is larger than height?

Tags: html, css

I have a page where I want to put a card around the content. The card is in a `.container` div to provide some padding, and that div is in a `.page` div that is the height of the viewport and that scrolls on overflow. I want the card to fill the height of the page when the content is not big enough to overflow the page, but I want it to stretch with the content when that *is* the case.

I can't use vh or any other absolute height, since there is a menu bar at the top of the page, and I want a generic solution.

I have a minimal example below. As you can see, the card doesn't stretch to the height of the page, even though the `min-height` is set to 100%.

```css
.page {
  height: 400px;
  border: 2px solid black;
  overflow: auto;
}

.container {
  height: fit-content;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 2px solid green;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.inner {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: fit-content;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

.content {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(50, 50, 50, .2);
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="inner">
      <div class="content"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Would using `calc` be a solution? Like `min-height: calc(100vh - 80px)` assuming your menu bar is 80px?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan The page doesn't technically 'know' about the menu, since they're different components. So your solution, while potentially working, would introduce coupling we wouldn't want

Comment: @JorisWillig I didn't really understand your reponse to Douwe de Haan, could you use JS to calculate the height of the menu, would that solve the issue?